# What is the difference between a vector valued function and a vector field?

Tags: vector-analysis, vector-fields

I think that I understand that if I parameterize $y=x\,$ I can write it as $f(t)=(t,t)\,$. So I'm assigning position vectors (coming from the origin) to the point $(t_0,t_0)$ for $t=t_0$. So I can say that that a vector valued function takes a scalar parameter and assign to a vector in $R^n$. And if a $(x,y)$ is going from $R^2$ to $R^n$, it is a vector field, because for **each position vector** I'm associating a vector ? (instead of each scalar $t$)

I'm confused because if vector valued functions can be going from $R^2$ to $R^2$ isn't it just like a vector field? (for each vector position I receive another vector in that point).

Comment: By "vector field" we usually mean a function $\mathbb{R}^n\to\mathbb{R}^n$ (or $U\to\mathbb{R}^n$ for some subset $U\subset\mathbb{R}^n$). In particular, the domain and codomain have the same dimension; we think of the input as a *point* and the output as a *vector* emanating from that point. But this perspective is secretly using the natural affine connection on $\mathbb{R}^n$. A vector field is really a section of the tangent bundle of a smooth manifold: i.e., a function that takes in a point $p$ in a smooth manifold $M$ and returns a vector in $V_p$, the fiber over $p$.

Answer (score 3):

Sure.  If you are in a region $U \subset \mathbb{R}^n$ a vector field on $U$ is a vector valued function on $U$ (taking values in $\mathbb{R}^n$).

In my mind (although maybe there are different conventions) a "vector valued function" is just any function from some space to a vector space. (I'm intentionally being a bit vague by what I mean by a "space", but most reasonable subsets of $\mathbb{R}^n$ you could write down should be fine) In particular you could define a vector valued function from some region in $\mathbb{R}^3$ to $\mathbb{R}^2$ if you wanted to.

A vector field is something more specific, it is an assignment to each point a vector inside the tangent space of your space at that point.  As you suggested, for some open set $U \in \mathbb{R}^2$ this is just the same as a vector valued function $U \to \mathbb{R}^2$. However if instead our space is the unit circle $S^1 = \{(x,y) |x^2+y^2 = 1 \}$ in $\mathbb{R}^2$,  then a vector field on $S^1$ is a map from $S^1$ to $\mathbb{R}^2$ with the condition that the vector assigned to a given point is tangent to the circle at that point (a harder condition to meet than just being an arbitrary vector valued function).

Comment: So if I parameterize a circle the vector space would be full of vectors tangent to the circle in each point of the circle? So, perpendicular to the position vectors of the vector valued function?

Comment: What do you mean by tangent space? I don't see how the vectors in a vector field have to necessarily be tangent to anything.